# Generador de numeros con Random

Tags: java

Alguien me podría decir como hacer una especie generador de números aleatorios con la función random (que lance varios numeros aleatorios al mismo tiempo).

Gracias.

Comment: ¿Puedes ser más especifico, compartiendo ejemplos concretos de lo que quieres? Y lo ideal sería que compartas lo que has investigado e intentado por tu cuenta también.

Comment: Gracias por el comentario, si ya investigue un poco, pero creo que ya me está dando resultado, tenía un problema que ya he resuelto, pero pues, lo que quería hacer era que el generador me diera unos numero aleatorios para asignarlos a un arreglo de objetos, que cada posición tuviera como una identificación, por decirlo así, ahora que termine subo el código, gracias te todas formas :D

Answer (score 2):

dejo un ejemplo tal ves te ayude:

```
public class GenerarNumerosApp {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

       System.out.println("Generar Numeros entre 10 y 100, con decimales (sin incluir el 10 y el 100)");
       //Generar 1000 numeros
       for (int i=0;i<1000;i++){
          double random=Math.random()*(100-10)+10;//(int)Math.floor(Math.random()*(num_maximo-num_minimo)+num_minimo).
          System.out.println(random);
       }

     }

}
```

Saludos!

Comment: Muchas gracias!!
Saludos!!

Comment: Samuel, no deberias responder a la pregunta. El autor ni se ha molestado en poner "random java" en google, lo que le habria dado tu respuesta y 100 más.